# VS2012 - Add WPF existing user control to project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

This seems like it should be pretty simple but I can't seem to make it happen. Lets say I have an existing project with a user control named uc1. I would like to use this user control in another project. I right-click the project name in the solution explorer and select add>existing item, change the drop down to all files and select the files uc1.xaml and uc1.xaml.vb. This of course adds the files to the project but there is no correlation between the xaml and the code behind file and there is no way to use the control. What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This of course adds the files to the project but there is no correlation between the xaml and the code behind file and there is no way to use the control. What is the proper way of doing this?

Normally, you'd add a reference to the other project, and use the UserControl directly.

This allows you to build a single project with your UserControl, and use the resulting assembly (DLL) in multiple projects *without duplicating the code*.

Comment: Thanks for the response. OK so if I am understanding this correctly, I should create a new project of type WPF Custom Control Library to house all of my user controls and then just reference the compiled dll from my other projects? This way I have access to the xaml and be able to visualize the control as I am creating it?

Comment: @dkirkdrei You probably want "WPF UserControl Library", not "Custom Control Library", but then, yes.

Comment: Yes, though it's better to use the WPF UserControl Libarary instead of Custom Control Library.

Comment: yep, your are correct! If only I had read down a little further in my project offerings ;) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 13):

Reed's answer is a good architectural one.  If you plan on creating a control that you will reuse in many projects then it's best to use a control library.

Your original question is valid in some situations though.  Say you have some source code from the Internet that you've unzipped to your drive.  This project contains a .XAML file and its linked .vb file that you want to add to a project.

As you seen, the Visual Studio Solution Explorer doesn't link the files when adding with the "Add Item" dialog.  I think this is a bug.  I find that if I reload the project, the affiliation is added.

Here's a workaround I use.  I drag the files from Windows Explorer /File Explorer onto the project in Solution Explorer.  That works correctly the first time.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however I had tried this but it does not work for me? When I drag the files from windows explorer into the solution explorer I immediately get a prohibition sign and the files do not copy over in any way. I am using VS2012 Pro if that make any difference.

Comment: I have VS2012 Ultimate, but I doubt that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you dropping on the project node?  I assume you are not debugging the app when dropping.  Solution explorer has supported drag-drop for years.

Comment: In VS 2019 I had to drag and drop to the project itself in solution explorer (Wpf2 in this case), dragging to an empty space didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse your user controls you need to create a new project and choose "Class Library" from the list of available projects. When compiled this class library can easily be used by any number of other projects and solutions simply by adding a reference to compiled DLL created when you build this class library.

Edit: As mentioned in other answer it's "WPF UserControl Library", not simple "Class Library"...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the .xaml file and VS should auto add the code behind(nested). I've seen this not work a few times and as @Walt Ritscher said this is probably a bug.

I found simply restarting Visual Studio and reloading my solution worked.