# Adding existing user control to WPF project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

When I add an existing user control to a project, I go to "Add existing item" and then choose both the .xaml and the .xaml.cs files for the user control.

After adding, the .cs file seems to be dissociated from the .xaml file, although everything builds properly.

Is there a better way to add existing user controls, since the user control actually consists of two files (the .xaml view and the .xaml.cs code behind)?

Comment: By dissociated you mean the xaml.cs file not nested under .xaml file and they appear two separate files?

Comment: @sthotakura yes

Comment: Not really sure, if there is a way to nest files while adding them to a project. You could manually edit the .csproj file to nest one file under another. Alternatively, you could use extensions like: [File Nesting extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ebde8fb-26d8-4374-a0eb-1e4e2665070c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS2012 - Add WPF existing user control to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072256/vs2012-add-wpf-existing-user-control-to-project)

Answer (score 0):

you have to check your namespaces . i think the problem is that . after changing xaml namespace go to cs and change the name space and after that go to InitializeComponent() method definition and change its namespace too . 
hope it work

Comment: I agree with this user.  If you edit a usercontrol before adding it as an existing item, I found VS2022 imports them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in VS2019 and come across the same problem - trying to reuse multiple User Controls from another project. Here is some finding/workaround -

- After right click and select "Add -> Existing Item..." Select **one**
  .xaml file (of your User Control), and do **not** include .cs files.
  Click Add and both the .xaml and .cs file will be added, and in the
  nicely associated way.
- If **multiple** User Control .xaml files are added at the same time -
  with or without the .cs files - this does not work. The .cs files won't
  be associated with .xaml files.

Not any clean solution but hope this helps a bit.